# Remove trailing spaces in Kate

Tags: kate

I am using Kate for editing some source code.
Unfortunately, I have lots of trailing space in there.
Is there a simple way to clean the whole text document?
I believe there is a simpler way than using a complicated Find/Replace operation with Regular Expressions.

Comment: Seems like there is a build in option for automatically remove the spaces on save: https://kate-editor.org/2012/10/27/remove-trailing-spaces/

Comment: Many thanks. Arggh I overlooked that option. This option is sufficient for my needs when the document is cleaned up once I save it. In the mean time I found another solution. One can use the "rtrim" operation in the command line that opens when "F7" is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is as mentioned in the comments: You can define the behavior on save in the `Open/Save` config page as described in this blog: https://kate-editor.org/2012/10/27/remove-trailing-spaces/